# How to get content in the meta tag?

Tags: flutter, dart

I got the DOM from any website. but I can't find a way to parsing content in meta.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:html/parser.dart';

void getMetaContent() {
    http.Response response = await
    http.get(url);

    var doc = parse(response.body);
    var meta = doc.querySelector('meta');
}
```

how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a few libraries for this, you can try one of them:

[Metadata Fetch](https://pub.dev/packages/metadata_fetch)

[Alice](https://pub.dev/packages/alice/versions/0.0.4)